# MQL4: Object = (Class*)NULL;

Tags: c++, mql4

I came across this in a program I am trying to improve.

```
class Class1
{
    private:

    public:
       Class1();
       ~Class1();

    protected:

        Class2* Object2;   
};
Imbalance::Imbalance()
  {
   Object2 = (Class2*)NULL;
  }
```

Can someone tell me what the * means when you create the object and why when instantiating the class you would make the object = the class something null. Is there a book I can read on this? Or any good document or webpage on class and objects in MQL4, C++ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` in C++ mean it's a pointer to an object.

Initializing a pointer to `NULL` means that it's pointing to nowhere ( by the way `nullptr` would be a better alternative nowadays ).

Usually, at a moment in your code, you'll find some statement like:

```
if ( Object2 == NULL )       // if not pointing to an object 
     Object2 =  new Class2;  // create a new one
```

Most books on C++ explain pointers in depth.

So my first answer would be "The C++ programming language" from B.Stroustrup.

Some online tutorials:  [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson6.html) and [here](http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/pointer.html).

***Edit:  MQL4 language***

In MQL4 language, which was historically based on a C-like syntax constructs and recent (post Build 509 ) extensions brought some more ( borrowed from MQL5 domain ), the **`*`** is also a pointer to an object, and **`new`** creates an object dynamically.  But unlike C++, it's not a direct pointer to a memory place, but an indirect pointer using the concept of a [descriptor](http://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/object_pointers).

A predefined constant variable [**`NULL`**](http://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/void) means -- like in C++ -- that there is no value.  It can be assigned to variables of any other fundamental types without conversion. The comparison of fundamental type variables with the `NULL` value is allowed.

In "New-MQL4" ( post Build 509 ) `NULL` can also be compared to pointers to objects created with the `new` operator.

*(Thanks to user3666197 for the additional MQL4 specific info)*

Comment: Considering the level of this question, you should add a basic primer on C++, with special attention to pointers, `NULL` and `nullptr`.

Comment: I see. Im coding in MQL which doesn't support nullptr. The if null create object makes more sense. I have taken a few courses but not seen this shortcut before. I have enough now to digg deeper in the books knowing now what area Im in. Thanks all.